# Not able to add Public Calendar as Community User on Community

Tags: community, lightning-experience, lightning-community, calendar, public-calendar

I have added the `Calendar` component to a page on my `Salesforce Community`. When I login as a `Portal User` and try to `Add Calendar`, I don't see the `Public Calendar and Resources` option in the dropdown. The calendar I've shared with this portal user has given `Full Access` to my portal user too.

On top of that, I made sure to give the profile access to events, activities, and tasks. Is there a permission for accessing `Public Calendar and Resources` I'm missing?

The option for `Public Calendar and Resources` should be visible in the dropdown I've clicked on.

[image: Add Calendar Modal from the Calendar Component]

Comment: I'm also having this issue - the user can see the events on the calendar (if given a link to the event, i.e. https://domain.force.com/communityname/s/detail/00UID00000fakeID00), but cannot select Public Calendars under the "Add Calendar" dialog.

Comment: @DylanBowman what is the type of community user license: partner,  customer community or customer community plus ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are accessing the experience site as internal user or partner user, `Public Calendar and Resources` will be visible. If you are using customer community or customer community plus user, then this option will not be visible. Refer to this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_calendar.htm&type=5)

> - Internal users and partners users can add a public calendar to their Other Calendars section.
> - Customer users can’t access public calendars and events.

This seems to be a default behavior for customer community user.
The access level defined for a user on the calendar only defines what the user can do on the calendar when its accessible and not the ability to add public calendars .

Comment: I was able to test this out in a Dev edition org.

Answer (score -2):

Kindly follow these steps below :

1. Setup | Quick Find : Public Calendars and Resources

For reference : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_groupcal.htm&type=5

I hope this helps :)

Comment: The question mentions that the calendar is shared with full access - this article only mentions how to give access.